# Solving the factorial equation $(n + 4)! = 90(n + 2)!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Solve the equation below:

$(n+4)!
 = 90
(n+2)!$

I did this:

$(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)!
 = 90
(n+2)!$

$n^2+7n+12+90=0$

$n^2+7n+102=0$

Is there anymore to this?

Comment: You made a sign error with the $+90$. If you correct that mistake you will find the equation easier to solve.

Comment: "Is there anymore to this?"  No.  There isn't.  ... except you have a sign error.  $(n+4)(n+3) = 90$ so $n^2 + 7n + 12 -90 = n^2 + 7n -78=0$.  Okay, there's a *little* more.  Then answer has to be a positive integer and only one of the two roots can be positive.

Answer (score 4):

When you take the $90$ to the other side you need to subtract it. You'll get

$n^2 +7n +12 -90 = 0,$

$n^2 +7n -78 = 0,$

$(n - 6)(n+13) = 0,$

So $n = 6$ or $n = -13$.

Clearly $n = -13 $  doesn't make sense, so we conclude:

$n = 6$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you know that $$\frac{(n+4)!}{(n+2)!} = (n+4)\cdot(n+3) = n^2+7n+12=90$$$$n^2+7n-78=0$$The solutions to this quadratic are $n=6$ and $n=-13$, so we take $n=6$ to be our answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you! That's silly of me

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the quadratic if you wish, and that solves the problem. But if you simply divide through by $(n+2)!$ you obtain $$(n+3)(n+4)=90$$ and it is easy to see the factorisation of $90$ into two consecutive positive integer factors $(9\times 10)$. The quadratic method does make sure you don't miss the alternative (irrelevant here) $90=-10\times -9$. The fact that it is a quadratic means that you know that there are no more solutions.

Comment: Worth noting that "consecutive" means $b = a+1$ which means $a \approx b$ which means $a*b = 90$ and $a*b \approx a^2$ so $a\approx b \approx \sqrt {90}$ and as $a$ and $b$ are consecutive it follows that if there *is* a solution it is $n + 3 = \lfloor \sqrt {90}\rfloor = 9$ and $n+4 = \lceil \sqrt {90} \rceil =10$ or $n = 6$.

Comment: @fleablood good point!

Comment: It didn't occur to me to do simple factoring.  I went straight to the solving the quadratic....

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different (and to rip off Mark Bennett's answer):

$ab = k> 0$ with $0< a \le b$ means $a \le \sqrt {k}$ and $b \ge \sqrt {k}$. (and if $0< a < b$ then $a < \sqrt k$ and $b > \sqrt{k}$)

So $(n+3)(n+4) = 90$ means $n+3 \le \sqrt{90} \approx 9.smallchange \le n+4$

As $n+3$ and $n+4$ are consecutive we must have:

$(n+3) \le \sqrt{90} < (n+3) + 1$.

Or in other words $n + 3 = \lfloor \sqrt{90} \rfloor = 9$.

So $n = 6$.